# How to do advanced pagination

Tags: reactjs, caching, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to create pagination logic for my Table component, I'm using [antd](https://ant.design/components/table/).

I have a few requirements which are making it quite difficult to implement:

1. I would like to be able to sort by different columns
2. Have some kind of cache implemented, currently using the [apollo-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-client)
3. Be able to jump around within the table (Example: *should be no problem of going from pages 1 to 500 and then 3*)

I have an endpoint that accepts the input object:

```
{
  offset: Int,
  limit: Int, # How many records to return starting from the offset defined
  ...
  # Some sorting rules
}
```

Currently all Table implementation I've found are using some kind of dataSource which always is an array, which is great for a static lists or the endless scrolling effect.

This should have been implemented often before by others, so I would love to hear how others have solved this simple issue?

*If you think I should just drop the caching support, how would you even do that when most Table components accept an **array**?*

Comment: Im not sure I understand the issue.. Why array is a problem? Array is one of core concepts in GraphQL and Apollo client knows how to deal with them.

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/pagination.html

Comment: The problem is when using fetchMore I will append the result. So if I go directly to page 3 instead of 2. I will have an datasource array with pageSize * 2. so page 3 will seem empty.

Comment: @Jeggy what did you end up doing?

Comment: Didn't come up with a better solution. So I'm just fetching the current data based on which page the user is on, so if the user goes from page 5 then 100 then back to 5. It will fetch the items on page 5 twice.